# Visual Studio Find Using Regular Expression Look Behind

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013, how would I find all occurrences of Sheet but not if it is MVC.Sheet?

I cannot figure out look behind.

This works to find ones that are not followed by .Index: Sheet(?!.Index)

Comment: According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) VS2013 uses the .NET's regex syntax. Which means you might use `(?<!foo\s)bar` which will match `bar` in `test bar` but not in `foo bar`

Comment: Thanks @HamZa I had tried that but I could not find look behind in the documentation. Either way it doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinSwarts, You need to look more thoroughly — regex reference quick reference [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on that page.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you both. That took care of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Working in VS2013 (see screenshot):

```
(?<!MVC\.)Sheet
```

- The `(?<!MVC\.)` lookbehind asserts that what precedesis not `MVC.`
- `Sheet` matches `Sheet`

[image: Visual Studio]

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)